# Video time reduced while conversion using ffmpeg and php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am converting video files to .flv using ffmpeg and php.
Here is my code

```
$cmd = $this->ffmpeg . ' -i ' . $filein . ' -sameq -ar 22050 -b 2048k -f ' . $parameters['convert'] . ' ' . $fileout;
```

Where `$parameters['convert'] = flv`

Its working great for many files, but when i upload and `~80MB and ~9minutes .mp4 file`, its is successfully converted to flv but the time reduces to 2 seconds. What may be the problem and possible solution.

upload limit is set to 200MB

Comment: Do not use `-sameq`. See [`sameq` does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524). Please try ffmpeg directly, and include the complete console output.

Comment: I have already tried removing `-sameq`. i know it means same quantizer

Comment: That's less important than including the ffmpeg console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Can you put your first comment as an answer, so that I can accept it. It worked by updating the ffmpeg and then removing `-sameq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to keep the "same quality" (-sameq means "same quantizers") use:

> ffmpeg -i leaving.mp4 -c copy -copyts leaving.flv

(-copyts "copy timestamps" is helpful to keep audio/video synced when converting formats)

You should *never* use -sameq when converting formats. (You are going from mp4 to flv.) If you were downsampling an mp2 to an mp2 or something similar, you might want to copy the quantizers and you'd use -sameq.

As for changing time, whenever you convert sample rates, you run the risk of programs calculating the length wrong. ffmpeg doesn't always calculated the length of 48k mp3s correctly, for example. Try upsampling a 44.1k mp3 to 48k and then check the length of each file in ffmpeg and Windows Media Player. You might get 4 different lengths for the same file.

Comment: Thanks... The problem was already solved by @LordNeckbeard's solution, and this solution is quite similar to that. I am accepting this in order to let other users know what works for me in above case. +1 for conversion suggestions.